# Value only showing the first item in SSRS report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report

So my problem here is that I have a Part number which lives in two warehouses hence it has two bin locations. If I just use `=Fields!PrimBin.Value` it only ever returns the first location. I need to display the PrimBin if the location is from a specific warehouse. To get the warehouse I use `=Fields!WarehouseCode.value`

What I need to do is only show the `PrimBin.Value` of `MAINWHSE` and not `CELLWHSE`

Thanks in advance.

Ok so the database it quite vast. However, for the information required I am using two tables. Part and PimWhse.

Part shares the Product ID to PrimWhse. In PrimWhse each partID has two locations `"MAINWHSE", "CELLWHSE "`and 1 bin to pick in each warehouse giving to possible locations.

So `WarehouseCode.Value` will have the information for which warehouse the part is located. and `PrimBin.Value` will have the warehouse position ID stored in it.

This is all setup via report style within the Epicor system. When I create a query in business activity to look in `MAINWHSE` it shows the correct information.

However, in the report data builder I'm not able to set this query so I assume SSRS will be able to see of both theses possible values for `PrimBin.Value`!? If not I guess I need to work out how to add a query to report data builder, which at the moment does no seem possible?

Thanks again.

Comment: far too little information here. Edit your question add give examples of your data and expected values.

Comment: I've Updated the question, if there is specific info you need let me know. Cheers.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the design and render of the report?